# how to print all these blocks?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, fibonacci, series

I want to do pyramid like image.I can do  first block.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
        printf("%d",j);
        }
       printf("\n");

        for(int k=5;j<=k;k--)
       {
        printf("%d",k)
        }
       for(int z=0;z<=5;z++)
        {
        printf("%d",z);
        }
     }



}
```

[i want to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJbYI.png)

Comment: You need to be more specific about the trouble you are having.

Comment: We aren't going to write your code for you. What have you tried? What is working and what is not working?

Comment: It ıs not working i am already asking what should ı add?

Comment: `for(int k=5;j<=k;k++)` :  Not be executed or Not the end.

Comment: `j` isn't valid outside of `for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)`.

Comment: note There is a need to operate on the basis of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int n = 5;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){//print n lines
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j){//Repeated twice
            //print sequence of number
            for(int k = 1; k <= i; ++k){
                printf("%d", k);
            }
            //print space
            for(int k = 0; k < n - i; ++k){
                printf("  ");//2 times
            }
            //print reverse sequence of number 
            for(int k = i; k >= 1; --k){
                printf("%d", k);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");//one line end
    }
    return 0;
}
```